# How to pass value js controller to js controller?

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm the new of Alfresco framework. So I would like to pass the value from js controller to other js controller. I don't know how to pass. Example: the value of group name in workflow-form.js to sample-module.js.

Please give me an instructions.
Thanks advance.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your code of what you have tried to do already?

Comment: Nope... I juz only want to know how to passed value and how many ways in javascript to javascript just as sample or reference in alfresco. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to pass variables between controllers, you should declare variables in the model like this:

```
var newVar = document.properties.name;
model.newVar = newVar;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it by using setOptions method in alfresco.js.